# React Native Swipeable min activation distance

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

Is there a way to set a minimum activation swipe distance with the `Swipeable` component from `react-native-gesture-handler`? Currently, if the user is trying to scroll inside a `ScrollView` (without height to scroll), it is possible to instead trigger the swipeable gesture seemingly by accident. If there was a minimum drag distance before triggering the swipeable state/animation, that could help dramatically. Does this exist? My screen typically does not have enough items to scroll, but can occasionally, so this is a bit distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I realized that `Swipeable` passes its props to an underlying `PanGestureHandler`, I was able to use a mixture of `activeOffsetX` (minimum horizontal distance before activation) and `failOffsetY` (prevent activation if straying vertically before activation) to achieve what I desired.

```
<Swipeable
  activeOffsetX={[-30, 30]}
  failOffsetY={[-30, 30]}
>
  {children}
</Swipeable>
```